# Is it possible to statically specify AWS::StackName inside a cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to statically specify AWS::StackName inside a cloudformation template? Or can this only be specified as a parameter when you run the template?

As far as I understand, this value can only be read via pseudo parameters, not set:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-stackname

Comment: You question also answered my question: AWS: How does CloudFormation know a template has been deployed?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645741/aws-how-does-cloudformation-know-a-template-has-been-deployed

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/247

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't.

Template is just a content of your stack, it doesn't set it's metainfo (like name, deployment region etc.).

Note, that you can use same template for multiple stacks, or even sub-stacks.

Comment: Yes, but would be nice to have the option to specify a naming template or pattern for a default stack name (i.e. 'MyDefaultStackName' + uniqueid) the way you can for Parameter defaults.

Answer (score 2):

A less than ideal but usable workaround if your goal is just to standardize stack name on manual AWS Console deployments can be to add a "fake" Parameter that a user can copy and paste.

```
...
  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    ParameterGroups:
      - Label:
          default: "Stack Name Config"
        Parameters:
          - StacknameToCopy
    ParameterLabels:
      StacknameToCopy:
        default: Stack Name to Copy

Parameters:
  StacknameToCopy:
    Type: String
    Description: Copy and paste this stack name above when deploying
    Default: SPECIFIC-naming-convention-123
```

Programmatic option would require using a framework like serverless.com or an AWS SDK/CLI wrapper.

Comment: good thing nobody is planning on using CloudFormation for automation!

Answer (score 1):

Old..but if anyone is still looking for an answer:

You can specify the stack name inside cloudformation by using the intrinsic function Fn::Sub :

!Sub ${AWS::StackName}

ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html

Comment: This allows you to GET, but not to SET the stack name.

Answer (score 0):

Specify that in the samconfig.toml as

```
[dev]
[dev.deploy]
[dev.deploy.parameters]
stack_name = "MyStackName"
```